# Anyway to make a IList.Contains() act more like a wildcard contains?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, ilist

I am trying to parse thru a csv string, put the results into a IList collection and then trying to find a way to do a wildcard 'contains' based on what was passed in.  Right now I have the following:

```
    public static IList<string> DBExclusionList
    {
        get 
        {
            Regex splitRx = new Regex(@",\s*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            String list = (string)_asr.GetValue("DBExclusionList",typeof(string)); 
            string[] fields = splitRx.Split(list); 
            return fields; 
        }
    }
    if (DBExclusionList.Contains(dbx.Name.ToString())==false)
    {...}
```

So if the string I am parsing (key value from .config file) contains:
    key="DBExclusionList" value="ReportServer,ReportServerTempDB,SQLSentry20,_TEST"

The DBExclusionList.Contains() works very well for exact matches on the first 3 items in the list, but I want to be able to ALSO have it for any partial match of the fourth item '_TEST'

is there any way to do it?  I could certainly hardcode it to always exclude whatever but I'd rather not.

thanks.

Comment: using Report Server, you have my sympathies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Linq :

```
if (DBExclusionList.Any(s => s.Contains(dbx.Name.ToString())))
```

Comment: I went with this one since the .Any returns a bool.  thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using .NET 3.5, you could use the Where() LINQ extension method:

```
DBExclusionList.Where(item => item.Contains(dbx.Name.ToString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex to split.  Use `string.Split()` and delimit your `_asr.GetValue("DBExclusionList)` with something like semi-colons.

Each item in `_asr.GetValue("DBExclusionList)` should be a regex pattern, so you check against each one in turn.